# replacing field in queryset before return

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following view -

```
class DeployFilterView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DefinitionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        jobname = self.request.GET.get('jobname')
        if jobname.count("\\") == 1:
            jobname = jobname.replace("\\", "")
            queryset = Jobmst.objects.db_manager('Admiral').filter(jobmst_name=jobname).exclude(jobmst_prntname__isnull=False, jobmst_dirty='X')
        else:
            parent, job = jobname.rsplit('\\', 1)
            queryset = Jobmst.objects.db_manager('Admiral').filter(jobmst_prntname=parent, jobmst_name=job).exclude(jobmst_dirty='X')
        return queryset
```

In that view there's a value field called "jobmst_runbook" which has a character that doesn't translate with the DRF XML renderer.  What I'd like to be able to do is scan the queryset for a particular character - SOH or \u0001

If it finds this character I want to remove it before doing the `return queryset`

Comment: It might be helpful to include the traceback of the error you are getting.

Comment: it doesn't return an error.  The character is a Character Code embedded into the DB column/Django Model.  When I return JSON with DRF it works and returns the character.  When I return XML it fails because the renderer hits the SOH character and doesn't know what to do.

Comment: What do you mean by ’it fails'? Doesn't it return an error then?

Comment: see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25578424/django-rest-framework-xml-special-character - error it returns is XML Parsing Error: not well-formed.  I'm guessing a custom Parser is needed then?

Comment: Please don't open multiple questions about the same question, it makes it much harder to answer if you spread the information across multiple questions.

Comment: Understood however I've noticed the problem with SO is depending on how you ask the question you may not even get a response from people.  Case in point I got a response here yet the other one which is older has crickets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by doing the logic in my serializer.  The serializer is now looking for the object that's causing the failure and stripping out the character.

```
class DefinitionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    runbook_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_url')
#    dependencies = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)
    jobdep = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        source='jobdep_set', # this is the model class name (and add set, this is how you call the reverse relation of bar)
        view_name='jobdep-detail' # the name of the URL, required
    )
#    triggers = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)
    trgmst = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        source='trgmst_set', # this is the model class name (and add set, this is how you call the reverse relation of bar)
        view_name='trgmst-detail' # the name of the URL, required
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Jobmst
        resource_name = 'jobmst'
        depth = 2
        fields = ('jobmst_id', 'jobmst_type', 'jobmst_prntid', 'jobmst_active', 'evntmst_id',
                    'jobmst_evntoffset', 'jobmst_name', 'jobmst_mode', 'jobmst_owner', 'jobmst_desc',
                    'jobmst_crttm', 'jobdtl_id', 'jobmst_lstchgtm', 'runbook_url', 'jobcls_id', 'jobmst_prntname',
                    'jobmst_alias', 'jobmst_dirty', 'job_dependencies', 'job_events')

    def get_url(self, obj):
        if obj.jobmst_runbook == None:
            pass
        else:
            return force_text(obj.jobmst_runbook[:-5])
```